# Drawable advantage over bitmap for memory in android

Tags: android, bitmap, memory-management, drawable

This question is linked with the answers in the following question:

[Error removing Bitmaps[Android]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259851/error-removing-bitmapsandroid/4260269#4260269)

Is there any advantage of using Drawable over Bitmap in Android in terms of memory de-allocation ?

I was looking at Romain Guy project Shelves and he uses SoftReference for images caches but I'm unable to search where is the code which is de-allocating these Drawables when SoftReference automatically reclaims the memory for Bitmap. As far as I know .recycle() has to be explicitly called on the Bitmap for it to be de-allocated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my understanding, Bitmaps are typically better for performance if you don't need to do much image manipulation.  However, I have run into memory leaks when I don't manually recycle them.  My solution was to [write a class](http://blog.pseudoblue.com/2010/08/15/android-bitmaps-and-memory-leaks/) to help me manage my images that provides an easy way to recycle all my bitmaps at certain points in my application. It also provides an easy way to reuse already loaded resources (including Drawables).

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to call Bitmap.reycle().  This will be done for you in its finalizer.  Doing it in the finalizer means the allocation will be delayed until finalizers run, so when possible directly calling recycle() can help with memory management.

Comment: no .recycle() has to be called, I saw romain guy comment here somewhere on stackoverflow telling to do that as bitmaps are natively allocated and if that is not done it is a memory leak

Comment: You might want to check a users profile before you call them wrong.

Comment: @AustynMahoney Experts can be wrong too. Take the advice of an expert but don't religiously follow it.  "Checking a users profile" is much less important than proof. No proof or links were provided from anybody. Anyway good answer from hackbod.

Comment: An important thing to note along with this is that the finalizer isn't going to run unless it's not referenced anymore I believe.  So there may be some cases you still want to call Bitmap.recycle()

Comment: This isn't just an expert... She probably wrote the Android code we are talking about here.

Answer (score 0):

Acc. to [this page](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html), starting from API Level 11, the Bitmap pixel data is stored in the Dalvik Heap along with the associated Bitmap. Thus calling .recycle is actually not required, unless you want to reclaim the memory manually for further use. Be sure to de-reference the bitmap too, just as an added measure.

PS: This was the link which explains [hackbod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236398/hackbod)'s answer.