# Does Drawable takes less memory then a Bitmap?

Tags: android, memory, bitmap, drawable

I'm an noob in Android and new here .

I just know that Bitmap store images pixel by pixel and don't do any compress .

Is Drawable same as Bitmap ?
or
For the same image file , a Drawable is takes less memory then a Bitmap ？

Thanks for any response .

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570929/drawable-advantage-over-bitmap-for-memory-in-android

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A bitmap is a `Drawable`. A `Drawable` is not necessarily a bitmap. Like all thumbs are fingers but not all fingers are thumbs.

[The API dictates](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html):

> Though usually not visible to the application, Drawables may take a variety of forms:
>
> - **Bitmap**: the simplest Drawable, a PNG or JPEG image.
> - **Nine Patch**: an extension to the PNG format allows it to specify
>   information about how to stretch it and place things inside of it.
> - **Shape**: contains simple drawing commands instead of a raw bitmap,
>   allowing it to resize better in some cases.
> - **Layers**: a compound drawable, which draws multiple underlying
>   drawables on top of each other.
> - **States**: a compound drawable that selects one of a set of drawables
>   based on its state.
> - **Levels**: a compound drawable that selects one of a set of drawables
>   based on its level.
> - **Scale**: a compound drawable with a single child drawable, whose
>   overall size is modified based on the current level.