# ArrayList of Drawable or ArrayList of Bitmap?

Tags: android, arraylist, bitmap

I am getting one scenario where I have to store some images in `ArrayList` (`Bitmap` or `Drawable`).
When bitmaps come to mind then I think about memory issues like `OutOfMemory`.
Does `ArrayList` of `Drawable` make any difference? Or it will be Like `ArrayList` of `Bitmap`?
What should I use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570929/drawable-advantage-over-bitmap-for-memory-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting question ... Generalizing my answer as I don't know why you would need to use a `List` of `Drawable`/`Bitmap`.

To be honest I wouldn't use neither of them because:

1. Bitmaps: these objects occupy a lot of memory and storing these in memory can be harmful for sure sooner or later if you're not too careful. For example: Maybe you would like to send that list through an `Intent` to a different component. If you do that and the initial list is not destroyed you'll get into a case where you have doubled the amount of memory as the Bitmaps will be deserialized as new objects on the target component side.
2. Drawables: a [`BitmapDrawable`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.java) keeps a reference to its Bitmap, so I don't see it to provide some benefit over the Bitmap itself. You may "forget" to clear your list of `Drawables` and this way you've memory leaked the Bitmaps. I don't think creating a `Drawable` is that time consuming or resource consuming to make it worth caching.

To add more, you have to cover all the cases where your activity is destroyed, re-created so that you don't leak the list.

Personally speaking, for Bitmaps downloaded from network, I would rather use a `LRUCache` to store the `Bitmap`, assign keys to them and backing them up to a disk cache. I would assign keys for each of them and work only with these keys. There are libraries like [`DiskLRUCache`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache), [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [novoda-ImageLoader](https://github.com/novoda/ImageLoader) that help you a lot.

Same applies for resource bitmaps: work only with keys - no need to cache them. The resource images should be small enough for your device size + density and big enough to fit your needs.

It's just my opinion ...